# `fit_generator` is not yet enabled for unbuilt Model subclasses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to utilize `Model.fit_generator` of Keras in **tensorflow 1.10**.

Simplified reproducible code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class TestNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, class_count, name='TestNet', **kwargs):
        super(TestNet, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.convolution = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(class_count, kernel_size=1, input_shape=(None, 3))

    def call(self, points):
        return self.convolution(points)

def segmentation_loss(labels, logits):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=labels, logits=logits)
    return tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

def generate():
    while True:
        yield (np.zeros(shape=(100,3)), np.zeros(shape=(100)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_net = TestNet(class_count=5)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    test_net.compile(optimizer, loss=segmentation_loss)
    history = test_net.fit_generator(generate, steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=10)
```

While this works in tensorflow 1.14, executing this in 1.10 yields the `NotImplementedError` in the title:

> NotImplementedError: `fit_generator` is not yet enabled for unbuilt Model subclasses

Anybody knows how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I see a mistake in `fit_generator`, update to this:

```
history = test_net.fit_generator(generate(), steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=10)
```

Now, I don't know how Tensorflow 1.10 works, but this kind of modeling is rather new, usually a Keras model is built like this:

```
#model's inputs
inputs = Input((None,3))

#model's layers
convolution = Conv1D(class_count, kernel_size=1)

#model's call
outputs = convolution(inputs)

#model finish
test_net = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

A workaround for you:

```
inputs = Input(shape)
test_net = TestNet(...)
outputs = test_net.call(inputs)
test_net_model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: changing to `generate()` throws the same error. In fact, the model does not even get to resolving the function. If I put a print at the beginning of `generate` I get nothing printed.
As for the Model construction, yes it is more common in beginners tutorials to use the sequential construction for simplicity, but it only works for very simple models without getting confusing. I think the object oriented definition of a model is much cleaner and in my case also the only one that works for the actual model.

Comment: No, it's not `Sequential`, it's `Model`. You can build **anything** with `Model`, there is no limitation and it's Keras standard way of working.

Comment: @Miiller, the only thing that might prevent you from achieving your goal with `Model` like I did is if you need to use "eager mode", otherwise that's the way to go. If you do need "eager mode", then I'm afraid you should update your packages.

Comment: Obviously it is not `Sequential`, but it is sequential in the way that the graph structure and forward pass are defined parallely in a sequence of operations, which is the tensorflow way of setting up the graph. Keras is programmed in an object oriented way to bring more structure to the graphs and I prefer to keep it that way. Otherwise I might aswell just stick with plain tensorflow. I would rather write my own `fit_generator` around `train_on_batch` than breaking down my structured models into cluttered unreadable operations, if there is no other way to fix this. Thanks for the help though.